# reset the timer on second call

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

I am bit New here ...and learning Threading.Timer ... I have a timer in Window Service which fires a function at 16:48:00 ..I just want to Fire the Timer Again at 21:00:00 PM ...then 22:00:00 ...there is no fix timer interval between the timeslots

here is My Code what I have Tried:

```
  public partial class ASMSService1 : ServiceBase
    {
        private Timer myTimer;
        private DateTime inputDate;
        private DateTime yesterday;
        private DateTime today;

        public ASMSService1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {

            inputDate = DateTime.Today;
            today = DateTime.Today;
            yesterday = today.AddDays(-1);

         //time is Set here
            SetTimer(16, 48, 00);

        }


        private void SetTimer(int hours, int minutes, int seconds)
        {
            inputDate = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes).AddSeconds(seconds);
            String date1 = inputDate.TimeOfDay.ToString();
            if (DateTime.Now > inputDate)
            {
                inputDate = inputDate.AddDays(1);
            }

       if (date1.CompareTo("16:48:00") == 0)
        {
            myTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(new TimerCallback(FirstSlotOperations));
            myTimer.Change((int)(inputDate - DateTime.Now).TotalMilliseconds, Timeout.Infinite);
        }


        }


        private void FirstSlotOperations(object e)
        {
         //some operation    
         //Need to reset the Timer at 21:00:00

                     }


    }
```

I have found the timer.change From MSDN article ..But I am not sure How to implement it in my case

I have Tried Thread.sleep()..But I am looking for some alternative also if possible ..
any suggestion would be Helpful

Comment: Please descibe more precisely what do you want from the above code and what the purpose of using timer?

Comment: Did you check any examples [like this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timercallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Comment: Actually I need to perform Some Specific operation if program hit a particular time Set by Timer

Answer (score 1):

I think Artyom Kharlamov is right, if you provide more details about what specific functionality do you intend to achieve, there is a better chance to get an answer that is closer to what you need.

My take on what you have currently presented:

1. If you want the service to perform a specific operation whenever the time of the day is equal to a predefined value (for example 16:48 as per your provided code), i think your approach is kind of complicated since you could achieve this easier by using [Scheduled Tasks](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-au/windows/schedule-task#1TC=windows-7), which will also cover the case in which you're trying to perform an operation within your service not on a specific time of the day but every x amount of time.
2. The timer object doesn't seem to expose any property or method that will tell you how much time has ellapsed since it first started ticking, for that you can use properties and get the current time whenever SetTimer is called, set a property in the ASMSService1 class and get the difference with the current time when FirstSlotOperations is called.

Maybe this isn't exactly what you want to do but unless you get a little more specific about your expectations it's hard to address them efficiently.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any object to get current time. Just use:

```
private void FirstSlotOperations(object e)
{
    DateTime current = DateTime.Now;       
}
```

An object passed as an argument in callback function is timer object so you can't get data from it. You can use it only to operate on timer object for example.

```
private void FirstSlotOperations(object e)
{
    Timer t = e as Timer;
    t.Change(1000, 0);
}
```

Comment: I Edited my Subject ...Actually I want to retrieve the Time set by Timer (16:48:00) mentioned in Code ..Not the Current Time ..Apologize for that